# Unexpected token == when selecting id based on <select>

Tags: javascript

I have a some simple dice rolling code here:

```
var dselection = document.getElementById(dieselection);
            var dice = {
                if(dselection == 'd6') {
                  sides: 6,
                  roll: function () {
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
                    return randomNumber;
                  }
                }
                if(dselection == 'd8') {
                  sides: 8,
                  roll: function () {
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
                    return randomNumber;
                  }
                }
                if(dselection == 'd4') {
                  sides: 4,
                  roll: function () {
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
                    return randomNumber;
                  }
                }
                if(dselection == 'd10') {
                  sides: 10,
                  roll: function () {
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
                    return randomNumber;
                  }
                }
                if(dselection == 'd12') {
                  sides: 12,
                  roll: function () {
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
                    return randomNumber;
                  }
                }
                if(dselection == 'd100') {
                  sides: 100,
                  roll: function () {
                    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
                    return randomNumber;
                  }
                }
            }



            //Prints dice roll to the page

            function printNumber(number) {
              var placeholder = document.getElementById('placeholder');
              placeholder.innerHTML = number;
            }

            var button = document.getElementById('button');

            button.onclick = function() {
              var result = dice.roll();
              printNumber(result);
            };
```

When I try to check what dselection equals with `if(dselection == 'something')`, I get an error: `diceroller:80 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==`.

Why can't I check what dselection is here?  Shouldn't `document.getElementById()` get the value of the selection?

If it does why can't I simply compare it to the string chosen?

The dice needs to roll depending on what dieselection is.
Here is my select:

```
<select id="dieselection">
            <option value="d4">D4</option>
            <option value="d6">D6</option>
            <option value="d8">D8</option>
            <option value="d10">D10</option>
            <option value="d12">D12</option>
            <option value="d20">D20</option>
            <option value="d100">D100</option>

        </select>
```

Comment: Is `dieselection` a variable? If not it should be quoted

Comment: This is invalid syntax. You can’t use `if` statements in the middle of an object.

Comment: `dselection` is an element. Do you mean `dselection.value`?

Comment: An `if` inside a `var dice = {` is definitely unexpected. And so is the body of an object literal as the `if` block.

Comment: @j08691 it should be, I declare it here `var dselection = document.getElementById(dieselection);`

Comment: You want `var dice = { sides: parseInt(dselection.value.slice(1), 10), roll() { return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1; } }`

Comment: Unless `dieselection` is defined somewhere else `document.getElementById(dieselection)` should probably be `document.getElementById('dieselection')` if you have an element with the ID of `dieselection`

Comment: @j08691 You're right, I fixed that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, that gets it working, but if I change the select value it doesn't update after that.  Is there a solution I could do to have it roll depending on what is selected?

Comment: @wanderer0810 You will have to update `dice.sides` every time the select is changed. There's an event for that.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, thanks for your help!

Comment: It is usually helpful to show the relevant parts of your HTML for context. Even better provide a [MCVE]

Comment: @JonP I updated my answer to show the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for all those `if` statements. Don't you see the pattern that the value of the `sides` property is simply the numeric part of `dselection`? So just do:

```
var dice = {
    sides: parseInt(dselection.substr(1), 10),
    roll: function () {
        var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sides) + 1;
        return randomNumber;
    }
};
```

You're also not setting `dselection` to the value of the input. It should be:

```
var dselection = document.getElementById('dieselection').value;
```

Comment: Here's another version of the same thing: https://jsfiddle.net/dhLv3du4/

Comment: This returns NaN.  Do I need to specify to return the dselection value?

Comment: Turns out it was returning NaN because of my select tag.  No clue why, but whatever.

Comment: You forgot to use `.value` to get the value of the select.